# How we can select an object in selenium webdriver which id gets changed after clicking on submit button every time.?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Am using for loop it select object first time but after sumbit..it doesn't select object because id of object gets change after submission and error message display..

code snippet

```
   for(int i=4; i<10; i++)
         {
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/aside[1]/section/ul[2]/li[5]/a/i[2]")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/aside[1]/section/ul[2]/li[5]/ul/li[1]/a[1]/span")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".mr5.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.pull-right.ng-scope")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='0' and @placeholder='Enter name']")).sendKeys("test"+i);
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='0' and @placeholder='Enter partnumber']")).sendKeys("test"+i);

      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='product-description']")).sendKeys("test"+i);

      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-chosen-4' and @class='select2-chosen']")).click();
      Select Group =new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@ng-model='product.CategoryID']"))); 
      Group.selectByIndex(2);
```

The id below keeps changing every time

```
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='select2-chosen-4' and @class='select2-chosen']")).click();
```

and I am unable to find anything which is unique to this element.

Comment: Share the fire path and HTML element

Comment: <a class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">
<span id="select2-chosen-4" class="select2-chosen">--Select--</span>
<abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"/>
<span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
<b role="presentation"/>
</span>
</a>

Answer (score 0):

As per the html, try to find the WebElement by using className.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("select2-chosen")).click();
```